# Using python to search HTML like google

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-inspector

I have 2 URLs here, and when I use the google inspect element to search the html, it works like I expect it.

https://www.target.com/p/dualsense-wireless-controller-for-playstation-5/-/A-83377785?preselect=81114477#lnk=sametab
The link above has the words 'Get it by' using Inspect + CTRL F

https://www.target.com/p/2020-panini-nascar-prizm-racing-trading-card-blaster-box/-/A-80884690#lnk=sametab
The link above does not have the words

I want a way to search in python, if a URL has the words 'Get it by', but whenever I do it it says neither have 'Get it by' in the HTML. I then printed the HTML and compared it to what the inspect element shows, and it is way different. How do I get the same script that the inspect element shows?

```
targetsubstring = 'Get it by'
my_request = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.target.com/p/dualsense-wireless-controller-for-playstation-5/-/A-83377785?preselect=81114477#lnk=sametab")
my_HTML = my_request.read().decode("utf8")
print(my_HTML)
if targetsubstring in my_HTML:
    print('in stock')
else:
    print('oos')
```

[Out of stock product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBgCk.jpg)

[In stock product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZaws.png)

My main goal of this script, is to be able to check URL links from target, if a product is in stock.

Comment: Seems like you need to use a headless browser to get the URL, such as via Selenium, which will execute all the JavaScript and such, unlike if you just grab the HTML directly off the URL. Have you looked into any of the standard browser automation tools, Selenium included? Also I think having "I will pay for a solution" in your title is going to get this post downvoted or closed, it's not standard practice and that's why the site has a bounty system instead.

Comment: Take a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) - It's pretty easy to get started with and does most the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Still a rookie here. Thanks for letting me know, will change that that.

And I've looked into selenium a bit, gonna have to look into more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The availabilty of the item is rendered by JavaScript. You would have to wait for JavaScript to be loaded before scraping. A better idea would be to this [dryscrape](https://pypi.org/project/dryscrape/), it is easy and better to use.